# iGenerateAssetSymbols resourceBundle error in Xcode 15 - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode15, ios17

after updating to Xcode 15 and attempting to build my project, I'm encountering the following error in the file **GenerateAssetSymbols** "`Invalid redeclaration of 'resourceBundle'.`" With Xcode 14.3.1, I didn't have this issue, and my project was working fine.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this? I haven't been able to build my project.

[image]

Complete Error:

[image]

Comment: Where else it is declared? Go to the errors tab on the left panel and expand the error message. There should be a "'resourceBundle' previously declared here" message. Click on that and see where it takes you. Did you perhaps declare such a thing elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Hi, I only get that error and I have not declared it anywhere else.  edit the question adding the screen where the errors tab is displayed

Comment: *Expand* the error message on the left, as I told you to do. See that disclosure indicator “>”? Click on that.

Comment: How did you solved?? I also stuck on the same issue @JoseTovar

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Build Settings" of your target. Search "Generate asset Symbols" in there. You will find this option under "Asset Catalog compiler - option". Change it to "NO" if it is "YES".

Build Again.[image]